# Grouping using timestamp in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have a bunch of tasks that I would like to group by their due date, currently each on has a created timestamp and I would like to use that to then organise the elements.

```
Due Today
  Task 1
  Task 2

Due this week
  Task 3
  Task 4
  Task 5

General
  All remaining tasks would go here
```

Currently I am doing:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="task in tasks" class="list-item">
    <a>{{ task.name }}</a>
    <title title="{{ task.date.created | amDateFormat: 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm a' }}">{{ task.date.created | amCalendar }}</title>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I guess the part that confuses me the most is how to work out the timeframes for the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `groups` array in your controller and use a `filter` function to filter the tasks into groups.

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0eggp58/3/) with an example.

The javascript:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('TaskApp', ['angularMoment'])
        .controller('TaskController', TaskController);

    function TaskController($scope) {
        $scope.groups = [
            {
                name: "Due Today",
                value: {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 0
                }
            },
            {
                name: "Due this week",
                value: {
                    from: 1,
                    to: 7
                }
            },
            {
                name: "General",
                value: {
                    from: 8,
                    to: Infinity
                }
            },
            {
                name: "Late",
                value: {
                    from: -Infinity,
                    to: -1
                }
            }
        ];

        $scope.tasks = []; // your tasks array

        $scope.dueDate = function (dateTo) {
            return function(value) {
                var due = moment(value.date.due);
                var now = moment();
                var diff = due.diff(now, 'days');
                return diff >= dateTo.value.from && diff <= dateTo.value.to;
            };
        };
    }
})();
```

The HTML:

```
<html ng-app="TaskApp">
<body ng-controller="TaskController">
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ group.name }}</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="list-group" >
        <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | filter: dueDate(group)" class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
                    {{ task.name }}
                </h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">
                    Created: {{ task.date.created | amCalendar }}
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I wanted to do a late group, how might I do that?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example of Late Group.

Comment: Thanks so much that makes perfect sense.